# What is the impact without pids_limit parameter in Docker-compose version 3.x.x

Tags: docker-compose

I am going to upgrade `docker-compose` from `2.x.x` to `3.1.x`, so what is the impact without having `pids_limit` in `docker-compose` version `3.1.x`

Could you explain me about what is the use of `pids_limit` in `docker-compose` and same time can some one provide link for impact of without `pids_limit`.

Answer (score 0):

1. `pids_limit` allows you to limit the number of pid(s) generated within a container.
2. Potentially, an attacker could trigger a fork bomb  with a single command inside your container and lead to instability. One way you can protect agains this by using that flag. So, the deployer can choose to bump up or down this.

**Reading Material**
12. Docker Security - Mastering Docker by Russ McKendrick, Scott Gallagher

Comment: Suppose if I want to protect my container using this flag, then what would be the max pids_limit, and what is the default pids_limit.